# How can i fix alignment in custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

What i am trying to do is a custom dialog in android , and here it is in the picture :

[image]

And as you can see there is a big space between height and it's edit text , how can make all of the component in the second row to the left side or centered horizontally , here is my code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FullImageActivity2.this);
                    final TextView title = new TextView(FullImageActivity2.this);
                    title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    title.setText("Add To Cart");
                    title.setPadding(5, 10, 0, 10);

                    alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(title);

                    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(FullImageActivity2.this);
                     final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(50,50);
                     lparams.weight=(float) 0.25;
                     lparams.leftMargin=3;
                     lparams.rightMargin=3;
                     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    TableLayout table = new TableLayout (FullImageActivity2.this);
                    TableRow row0= new TableRow(FullImageActivity2.this);
                    TableRow row1= new TableRow(FullImageActivity2.this);


                    TableRow.LayoutParams tr1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    tr1.gravity=1;

                    //tr1.topMargin=15;
                    //tr1.bottomMargin=10;
                    row1.setLayoutParams(tr1);
                    row0.setLayoutParams(tr1);

                    final EditText height = new EditText(FullImageActivity2.this);
                    final TextView heightTxt = new TextView(FullImageActivity2.this);

                    final EditText width = new EditText(FullImageActivity2.this);
                    final TextView widthTxt = new TextView(FullImageActivity2.this);

                    final TextView hint = new TextView(FullImageActivity2.this);

                    height.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                    height.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                    width.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    //height.setPadding(3, 0, 3, 0);
                    width.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                    heightTxt.setText("height");
                    heightTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    heightTxt.setPadding(7, 0, 5, 0);

                    hint.setText("please enter height and width in meter");
                    hint.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    hint.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);

                    widthTxt.setText("width");
                    widthTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    widthTxt.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);

                    row0.addView(hint);
                    row1.addView(heightTxt);
                    row1.addView(height);
                    row1.addView(widthTxt);
                    row1.addView(width);
                    table.addView(row0);
                    table.addView(row1);



                   // ll.addView(height);
                    //ll.addView(heightTxt);
                    ll.addView(table);


                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(ll);

                    alertDialogBuilder

                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {



                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("Add",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                itemId=productname.getText().toString();
                                Height= height.getText().toString();
                                Width= width.getText().toString();
                                Image=imageForCart;
                                Log.e("item id",itemId+"");
                                Log.e("Height",Height+"");
                                Log.e("Width",Width+"");
                                Log.e("Image",Image+"");
                                AddToCart.add_to_class(itemId,Height,Width,Image);  
                                Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity2.this,"add successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent opencart=new Intent(FullImageActivity2.this,CartList.class);
                                startActivity(opencart);


                            }


                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();          
                        alertDialog.show();
```

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout parameter to the heightTxt and widthTxt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the values of `lparams`, try to calculate the screen size and choose values according to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide LayoutWeight to your Edittext as 1. It will cover up all the remaining space.
If you will provide LayoutWeight to both the Edittexts then they will divide the remaining space equally.

What right now happening to your code is its providing LayoutWeight 1 to the TextView of Height. so all the other components in that row are taking their minimum space and rest is occupied by Height TextView.

If you want to make them equal in size then provide LayoutWeight to all as 1.